# How to extract a row, given columns?

Tags: comma-separated-list

Given some columns of an array as comma-separated lists, how can I construct the array?

I figure if I can extract a specific row from a comma-separated list of such columns, then I'll probably be able to do the rest, but I can't even get the following code to compile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\colzero{0,0,1}
\def\colone{0,1,0}
\def\coltwo{0,1,1}

\newcommand{\getrow}[2]{%
    \xdef\rowans{}
    \foreach \x in #2 {
        \xdef\rowans{\rowans \pgfmathparse{{\x}[#1]}\pgfmathresult}
        }
    \rowans
}

\begin{document}
$\getrow{0}{{\colzero},{\colone},{\coltwo}}$
\end{document}
```

I somehow managed to figure out how to do this once before (using various things I found here on StackExchange), but now I just can't find any answers related to what I'm looking for.

Ideally I'm looking to do this with a variable number of columns, though not necessarily with a variable number of rows.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Do not put `\pgfmathparse` inside an `\edef`/`\xdef`. Do `\pgfmathparse{{\x}[#1]}\xdef\rowans{\rowans\pgfmathresult}` instead, for example. If you just do want to typeset the result, you don't need any `\xdef` or `\rowans` you can just do that in the loop: `\pgfmathprint{{\x}[#1]}`.

Comment: I still get the same error when I replace the relevant section with your suggestion: "Paragraph ended before \pgffor@next was complete".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using `expl3` and `xparse`; you define columns with a `\setcolumn` command and use `\getrow` that gathers the items in the chosen row and produces them with a separator given in the final argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\setcolumn}{mm}
 {
  \clist_if_exist:cF { g_ylab_column_#1_clist }
   {
    \clist_new:c { g_ylab_column_#1_clist }
   }
  \clist_gset:cn { g_ylab_column_#1_clist } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\getrow}{mmm}
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l_ylab_row_seq
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l_ylab_row_seq
     {
      \clist_item:cn { g_ylab_column_##1_clist } { #1 }
     }
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_ylab_row_seq { #3 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setcolumn{colone}{0,0,1}
\setcolumn{coltwo}{0,1,0}
\setcolumn{colthree}{0,1,1}

\begin{document}

\getrow{1}{colone,coltwo,colthree}{}

\getrow{2}{colone,coltwo,colthree}{, }

\begin{tabular}[t]{ccc}
\getrow{1}{colone,coltwo,colthree}{&} \\
\getrow{2}{colone,coltwo,colthree}{&} \\
\getrow{3}{colone,coltwo,colthree}{&}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

A `\setcolumn` command defines a `clist` variable if not already existent and (globally) sets it. You'll call it by *name* in a `\getrow` command that sets a `seq` variable with the items in the specified row. Then it produces the sequence with the chosen separator between items.

[image]

Note that, in `expl3` counting of items generally starts from 1 (which is more logical than starting from 0).